# How does $parse work?

Tags: angularjs

I have simple code like this:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <input type="text" ng-model="money" mask="2">
  <p>{{money}}</p>
</div>

angular.module("app", [])
  .directive("mask", function($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      require: "ngModel",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log($parse(attrs.mask)); // function(s, l, a, i){return 2;}
        console.log($parse(attrs.mask)(scope)); // 2
      }
    }
  });
```

Why the first output is `function(s, l, a, i){return 2;}`with `(s, l, a, i)`?

In case you need the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ealonwang/x1hcbpjw/11/

Comment: http://www.jomendez.com/2015/02/10/example-parse-angularjs-directive/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Angular Documentation for the $parse service](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/service/$parse)

$parse() without calling with `scope` as an IIEF, returns a function which is the evaluated expession, aka: `return 2`;

However this function that is returned takes multiple arguments:

> function(context, locals) 
>   a function which represents the compiled expression:
>
> context – {object} – an object against which any expressions embedded
>   in the strings are evaluated against (typically a scope object).
>   locals – {object=} – local variables context object, useful for
>   overriding values in context.
>
> The returned function also has the following properties:
>
> literal – {boolean} – whether the expression's top-level node is a
>   JavaScript literal. constant – {boolean} – whether the expression is
>   made entirely of JavaScript constant literals. assign –
>   {?function(context, value)} – if the expression is assignable, this
>   will be set to a function to change its value on the given context.

So what you are seeing is the evaluated but not immediately invoked function being returned from the service.

Listed below is the test cases that are ran against this service to explain how locals and context are used and defined:

```
var getter = $parse('user.name');
var setter = getter.assign;
var context = {user:{name:'angular'}};
var locals = {user:{name:'local'}};

expect(getter(context)).toEqual('angular');
setter(context, 'newValue');
expect(context.user.name).toEqual('newValue');
expect(getter(context, locals)).toEqual('local');
```

Specifically what those arguments mean are found here: [parse.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L1934).

`var value = parsedExpression(scope, locals, assign, inputs);`

Comment: Thanks. What is (s, l, a, i) in that function?

Answer (score 0):

if you use **$parse(attrs.mask)**  it returns the getter function of mask ..

when you use **$parse(attrs,mask)(scope)** you called the getter function on scope ...

if you use **$parse(attrs,mask).assign(scope, 'new value')** you will call the setter function on scope ..

Comment: I guess s is scope, l is element, a is attribute. And what is i?